# Minimum number of deletions for a given word to become a dictionary word

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

> Given a dictionary as a hashtable. Find the minimum # of
>   deletions needed for a given word in order to make it match any word in the
>   dictionary.

Is there some clever trick to solve this problem in less than exponential complexity (trying all possible combinations)?

Comment: if word can be in dictionary - 0, if word is for sure not in dictionary - 1

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense as written.  I'm guessing you are using the same word: 'dictionary' to mean two different things.  Otherwise, I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @JimmyJames You have a hashtable with valid words in it (look up costs O(1)). Program needs to find minimum number of deletions required for some given word (String w) to tranform to one from the hash table. Don't know how better to explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, suppose that you have a single word w in the the hash table and that your word is x. You can delete letters from x to form w if and only if w is a subsequence of x, and in that case the number of letters you need to delete from x to form w is given by |x - w|. So certainly one option would be to just iterate over the hash table and, for each word, to see if x is a subsequence of that word, taking the best match you find across the table.

To analyze the runtime of this operation, let's suppose that there are n total words in your hash table and that their total length is L. Then the runtime of this operation is O(L), since you'll process each character across all the words at most once. The complexity of your initial approach is O(|x| · 2<sup>|x|</sup>) because there are 2<sup>|x|</sup> possible words you can make by deleting letters from x and you'll spend O(|x|) time processing each one. Depending on the size of your dictionary and the size of your word, one algorithm might be better than the other, but we can say that the runtime is O(min{L, |x|·2<sup>|x|</sup>) if you take the better of the two approaches.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Just one thing when you say "You can delete letters from x to form w if and only if x is a subsequence of w", you mean iff w is a subsequence of x right?

Comment: @Weltschmerz Yeah... let me fix that. :-)

Comment: Similar to your point on my answer, if you can delete characters from middle of the word, this won't work, right?

Comment: This should work if you're checking whether the word is a subsequence of each dictionary word rather than a substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and then see where your given word fits into it.  The difference in the depth of your word and the closest existing parent is the number of deletions required.

Comment: Are you sure this works? If the optima choice is to delete the first letter from the word, then you'd end up searching the wrong subtree.

Comment: Good point.  I assumed the deletions were from the end but it doesn't say that in the question.